# How to set a "length" parameter in a weibull distribution. I'm trying to model a response curve of a direct mail marketing campaign over time

Tags: r, curve-fitting, weibull

I'm trying to fit a curve to model responses from a direct mail campaign over time.  Using R, I was a able to get a shape and scale factor using the fitdistr() function.  Then I use the shape and scale as parameters in the weibull() function.  However, our campaigns usually last 63 days (8 weeks) and the "length" of the fitted weibull curve gets cut off premature.  Is there any way to set the "length"?

...OR is there a better way to model Direct Mail marketing campaign responses???

Thanks!

```
set.seed(5)
install.packages("MASS")
library("MASS")
responses <-c(4,5,1,12,24,16,16,15,5,18,7,12,5,13,6,2,9,2,5,1,4,4,5,3,3,4,7,3,9,2,2,4,3,2,5,4,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)                                                                                        

f <- fitdistr(responses,'weibull')

f #check the shape and scale

#plug in the shape and scale. 284 is the number of total responders that we're trying to fit the curve to. 
weibulldraws <- as.data.frame(table(round(.5 +   rweibull(284,1.0753863,4.6579543))))
weibulldraws
```

Comment: You example isn't reproducible.  My hunch is that you're asking about a truncated weibull distribution but it's hard to tell.

Comment: are you looking for `curve(dweibull(x,shape_est,scale_est),from=0,to=63)` ??

Comment: Dason- I simplified the code to make it reproducible. Basically the output does not extend 63 days...

Comment: It's still not clear to me what your issue actually is.

Comment: @BenBolker

I'm getting an error when I run the curve function: 

**Error in curve(rweibull(284, 1.0753863, 4.6579543), from = 0, to = 63) : 
  'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing 'x'**

any suggestions?

Comment: Well your code doesn't make much sense since rweibull gives random observations from the weibull

Comment: @Dason

I guess I'm confused. I'm trying to model a curve based on a simulation which used rweibull to model responses from a marketing campaign. What am I missing?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you tabulate a vector with `table()`, only values that occur in the vector appear in the result; if you want to include other values, you need to create a factor with those values included as levels. Thus, if you want to include all the zeros at the end, make your result into a factor with the appropriate levels before tabulating:

```
set.seed(5)
wshape <- 1.0753863
wscale <- 4.6579543
n <- 284
rvals <- round(rweibull(n,wshape,wscale)+0.5)
frvals <- factor(rvals,levels=0:63)
weibulldraws <- as.data.frame(table(frvals))
```

If you instead wanted to draw the *theoretical* curve associated with the Weibull (i.e. a density curve rather than a table corresponding to a random draw from the distribution) then use `curve()` with the `dweibull()` function:

```
curve(n*dweibull(x,wshape,wscale),from=0,to=63)
```

(use `add=TRUE` to add the curve to an existing plot).

Comment: Thanks Ben! Your post answered what I was looking for. I think what was happening was the 0's were being truncated when I rounded output of the rweibull function.  Thanks for that.  (once my reputation gets above 15 I'll make sure to "vote up" your response :) )

Comment: I used the check box.  Thanks again for your response. VERY much appreciated.  Did you happen to see my question regarding the curve function above?  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm still getting the same error: _Error in curve(n * dweibull(284, 1.0753863, 4.6579543), from = 0, to = 63) : 
  'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing 'x'_

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: you're still misunderstanding how `curve()` works.  You want `curve(n*dweibull(x,...),...)` **not** `curve(n*dweibull(284,...),...)`

Comment: What does the parameter "x" represent?  I looked it up via ?curve and it said "x" is a "vectorizing numeric R function".  Not sure what that means. Also, what will "n" be?  Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: You should be looking at the description of `expr` instead.  `n` is what I specified in my code.  Try running my code *exactly as written* and trying to figure out what it does before generalizing to your own situation ...

Comment: Ah, explicitly using "x" for the first argument of the function seems to work. This is what I did: `curve(n*dweibull(x,1.0753863,4.6579543),from=0, to=63)`.  I'm still not exactly sure why inserting "x" for the first argument in dweibull works in this case since the command: `dweibull(x,1.0753863,4.6579543)` itself doesn't work.  Thoughts? Thanks again

Comment: Can you explain why `dweibull(x,10.753863,4.6579543)` doesn't work as stand-alone code?  It works when combined with the curve () function though as shown in my question above.  Thanks!

Comment: Because `curve()` is a "magic" function that interprets `x` as a dummy variable.  If you define `x` to be a vector of numeric values, then that statement should work.